# ol.Style.Icon and inline SVG

Tags: openlayers-3

there is any way use inline SVG in Icon?

`var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Icon( ({
                src: 'img/svg.svg'
            }))
        });`

works fine but I generate inline SVG in code

```
var icon = "<svg width=34 height=34 ><polyline  points='17,17 17,0 13,5 17,0 21,5' fill='none' stroke='blue' stroke-width='2' transform='rotate(263,17,17)'></polyline><circle cx=17 cy=17 r=11 style='fill:rgba(51,153,102,1);' /><circle cx=17 cy=17 r=6.5 style='fill:rgba(150,150,150,1);' /></svg>";
```

can i use this string like a source for icon? Or there is any possible way?

Answer (score 0):

You can display an overlay containing your inline SVG.

```
var icon = "<svg width=34 height=34 ><polyline  points='17,17 17,0 13,5 17,0 21,5' fill='none' stroke='blue' stroke-width='2' transform='rotate(263,17,17)'></polyline><circle cx=17 cy=17 r=11 style='fill:rgba(51,153,102,1);' /><circle cx=17 cy=17 r=6.5 style='fill:rgba(150,150,150,1);' /></svg>";

var overlayContent = document.createElement('div');
overlayContent.innerHTML = icon;

var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
    element: overlayContent,
    position: [0, 0],
    positioning: 'center-center'
});

map.addOverlay(overlay);
```

If you need to rotate your icon, you can get your overlayContent and modify his rotation like this :

```
overlay.getElement().style.cssText = 'transform: rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)';
```

I tried with an icon and put the string with "data:image/svg+xml;utf8" but there was some exception from OL3 in IE11 when I was moving my map. (Chrome was displaying everthing fine)

Anyway, using an overlay is more performant for me and I can modify the content of my icon (size, color, ...) without recreating each time an icon.

If you just need to rotate it, the ol.Style.Icon can do it on the fly; but you just need to see if there is no more bugs :)

Answer (score 0):

When using data:image/svg+xml we must url encode or base64 encode the svg element. I use https://restonk.com/SVGEncoder/ to encode inline svg's into my web pages. Something like this *should* work.

```
var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
image: new ol.style.Icon(({
    src:'data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20height=%22100%22%20width=%22100%22%3E%20%3Ccircle%20cx=%2250%22%20cy=%2250%22%20r=%2240%22%20stroke=%22black%22%20stroke-width=%223%22%20fill=%22red%22%20/%3E%20%3C/svg%3E'
}))});
```